# How do I set a Dokku environment variable that contains non-alphanumeric charcters?

Tags: environment-variables, dokku

I've been using `dokku config:set` to set environment variables for an app. This command uses SSH to set environment variables on the remote server that the app is deployed to.

Haven't had any problems with most of the environment variables I've tried to set using that command.  However a couple of the values contain non-alphanumeric characters and I get errors if I try to set those.

For one of the problematic env vars, I was able to escape all the non-alphanumeric characters and successfully use `dokku config:set` like so:

```
dokku config:set EXAMPLE_VAR=7\(I\@gxPwgmVg7h2R5a9C9I\}\;1\*c\[QVASnu\^\"\`\"\~\`\<c\`ge6=4\:Jrq\[R\!aqxdn6\>VPqhnx\`bt\@W
```

The other one I have not been able to set, despite escaping the characters and putting double quotes around the whole string like so:

```
dokku config:set EXAMPLE_VAR2="BN\)nj\":d8\=\`>\,B\<I\.VY\<$\1YZ\'SS}4mrMsZ\&\>6Ipqf$\^XmkeGkh8\/\|{0XT\.7z\:y\=\}\`"
```

The resulting error is:

```
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
FAILED: At least one env pair must be given
```

I have tried the `dokku confg:set --encoding` option with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1262#issuecomment-529894982, what I ended up doing was to connect via SSH to the Dokku server and edit `/home/dokku/YOUR_APP/ENV` directly to add the troublesome envronment variable.

Then doing `dokku ps:restart` or in my case `git push dokku master` did the trick for getting the app to use the new env var.